# Chained Comparison with Loop Explanation in Python

Tags: python, loops, sum, zip

Beginner Here! I came across some python code about the zip() function being combined with the sum() function, but the code does not make sense to me and I was wondering if I could get an explanation:

```
list_1 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b']
list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']

print(sum(a != b for a, b in zip(list_1, list_2)))
```

a and b are not defined, but are being compared? Is it also looping through "a" with `b for a`? What is `a` and `b` in this case? How are they being added together with `sum()`? What is being looped through? If I can have some help understanding this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When confronted with code like this, it's helpful to break it into bite-sized pieces and see what each does. Here's an annotated version:

```
list_1 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b']
list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']

print(list(zip(list_1, list_2))) # you need to pass this to  list() because zip is a lazy iterator
# correponding pairs from each list
# zip() trucates to the shortest list, so `c` is ignored
# [('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'b')]

print([(a, b) for a, b in zip(list_1, list_2)])
# same thing as above using a list comprehension
# loops over each pair in the zip and makes a tuple of (a,b)

print([a != b for a, b in zip(list_1, list_2)])
# [False, True, True, False]
# compare each item in those pairs. Are they different?

print(sum(a != b for a, b in zip(list_1, list_2)))
# 2 
# take advantage of the fact that True = 1 and False = 0
# and sum those up -> 0 + 1 + 1 + 0
```

It's also helpful for lookup things like [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip), and [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions), although for many it makes more sense when you see them in action.

Comment: Thank you so much! This made everything so much more clear!

Answer (score 1):

The `for` construct in the code is a generator.  This form of generator is typically seen in a list comprehension, but it can also be passed directly to a function that wants an iterable, such as `sum`.

If you want to see what the generator actually produces, you can do:

```
x = [a != b for a, b in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
x = list(a != b for a, b in zip(list_1, list_2))
```

The values in the list `x` are `bool` values that are `True` where values in the two lists compare unequal and `False` where they compare equal.  If one list is longer than the other, the values past the shorter list are skipped.

Back to your code, instead of creating a list, it's left as a generator and passed directly to `sum`, which will operate on any iterable.  Since `bool` values are just integers (with `False = 0` and `True = 1`), this just sums the number of differing values between the two lists (ignoring the extra values in the longer list).